# Rational Application Developer freezes when opening XML files

Tags: xml, freeze

When I try to edit an XML file in the XML Editor of Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software version 7.5.4, the program becomes unresponsive.

- title bar has "(Not Responding)" appended to it
- menu bar disappears
- cursor switches to hourglass
- window can be dragged and it gets repainted normally
- window can be minimized and restored

The application must be terminated and restarted before it can be used. Also, the XML files can be edited normally through the Text Editor.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do the XML files contain remote entities (like a DTD)? If the remote resource is unavailable or bandwidth is limited, the editor's parser may block waiting for the network resource.

Comment: Sorry to say this but I found RAD is the worst IDE to work on !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that problem was the SpringIDE plugin. For whatever reason, it would cause the app to hang when any XML file was opened. I uninstalled the entire application and reinstalled without the plugin and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the xml file very large? Eclipse (which RAD is based on) had a bug for a while that caused this problem for very large xml files and/or xml files that were somewhat large but all in one line (i.e. no hard line breaks). If either of these is the case, you might try waiting longer... if I remember right it finally would become responsive again. If you can edit the file you could try adding line breaks if there are none.

Stupid bug... thought that it was fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is quite small. Maybe double the size of my original post. And there are hard breaks. One time I left it to try over lunch to no result. I'm going to try putting it on another machine to see if there is something outside the software that is causing the problem.